# is it possible to use bootstrap together with MDBootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, mdbootstrap

I Have been using Bootstrap for many years, and it is been 9 days now that I am working on a project in which I used bootstrap CDN, the problem is I need some features, components of MDBootstrap but not all of it, and when I included MDBootstrap also, it conflicted with the bootstrap cdn, my buttons and all the components I used are now confused, some of my components corrupted, what is the solution? I will write down my CDNs I have used.

```
    <!-- Google Fonts Roboto -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap"
/>

<!-- MDBootstrap CDN -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/4.2.0/mdb.min.css"
/>

<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

and these are all what I have at last of the body tag.

```
<!-- MDB -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/4.2.0/mdb.min.js"></script>

<!-- FontAwesome CDN -->
<script
  src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d455f30832.js"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<!-- Bootstrap js -->
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

any solution would be really appreciated.
please consider upvoting my question that I need for reputation. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

As per bootstrap support team: Import only our package. With this package you'll be able to youse both: mdb, and standard bootstrap.

Reference: https://mdbootstrap.com/support/standard/can-i-use-bootstrap-with-mdbootstrap-can-i-use-bootstrap-and-mdbootstrap-together/

Comment: I did that, I only imported their CDN, but it doesn't work, how do I implement that? because their buttons are different, some of their classes apply different styling.

Comment: :( You asked wrong question then. You should have asked how to overwrite default styles of MDBootstrap with default bootstrap styling. with this button example. Anyways, instead of importing bootstrap again create your own css style file and import it at the end of the code and copy specific style code of bootstrap.css in that file specific to button.

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L3008 from line 3008 to 3364

Comment: hmmm you mentioned about button style in your question... I take my words back